# Trying to locate an old scifi short story about people permanently locked in rooms

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember having read as a child a short scifi story with the following approximate plot:

We follow some young guy who has been locked all his life in a room/small apartment with a TV and some books. His books revolve around electronics and telecommunications, and so he is able to tune his TV (or something like that) so that he can see other people locked in their rooms, all identical to his, like in a kind of prison (but with different kinds of books, if I remember
right). Then he finds an interesting young woman in her room and sets a way to communicate with her. They speak for some time (I don't remember the details), and they fall in love. They try to go out so that they can meet, but their doors won't open. Finally they devise a way to force them (perhaps by finding some guy with books about doors and locks?), and in the end

> as they are going out to meet, she says to him through her intercom: "Look at how white the Moon is!", but he, after a pause, replies: "No. The Moon is GREEN".

I think I may have read it in a Spanish "Nueva Dimensión" magazine (should be a translation, but it could happen to be from a Spanish author), so it may have been written between 1945 and 1983, with 1960-1970 being more probable.

Comment: What is the significance of the moon color?

Comment: @Buzz possibly it indicates they're actually in different Dimensions. Granted it's not clear if they meet in person, not sure why they need intercoms.

Comment: @Buzz The story plays with the implicit intuition that, since all these locked people are in very similar rooms, they are in some kind of prison. But when the two of them finally find a way to escape their rooms, they see different moons, so they are on different planets. Hence the implications that humanity is kind of prisoner along several planets.

Comment: @JohnC They need intercoms because they are locked in rooms without the possibility of going out. That's the wole premise of the story: everyone is locked, but one of them is able to establish telecommunications with others.

Comment: @JoseBrox I got that, it was the line "they go out to meet" making me confused - possibly they had not yet met (and never would), and so still needed the intercoms.

Comment: @JohnC Ah, ok! English is not my native language, I can edit it for better clarity: how could we convey in that sentence that they go out believing they are going to meet at the next moment (without spoiling the ending yet)?

Comment: I edited in my suggestion, if you don't like it, you can revert it, but I think that is what you trying to say.

Comment: Would Earth look green from the moon? Possibly one's on Luna and one's on Terra (it doesn't really matter, I got no idea about the story)

Comment: @JohnC Yes, thank you. It is better now.

Comment: @DannyMcG It could be, but we don't really know; that is why this short story felt so rewarding as a kid and was never forgotten: its ending, with that indirect implication, opened an array of dismaying possibilities.